# Additional monitor to laptop with HDMI to VGA convertor randomly disconnects

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, vga

I am ubuntu 18.04, with `Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)` and since i had a spare old vga monitor lying empty i thought of using it as a dual monitor.
I have purchased [HDMI to VGA](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B01MR32IZE/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) adapter to connect the monitor to my laptop.

It works fine, shows up in displays list.

Now the issue is, the screen suddenly (almost within 5mins), gets disconnected and my monitor shows no signal. Fiddling with the connections (nudging and pushing it) does not yield any difference - but if i completely disconnect and then reconnect the monitor starts displaying.

What i tried so far:

1. Changing resolutions for the addl monitor
2. Changing the refresh rate

I really do not have an idea on whats going wrong, or to debug it. Any ideas?

```
me@me-0020:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2646 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1280x720+0+48 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 372mm x 209mm
   1280x720      59.86*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

me@me-0020:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)
me@me-0020:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for me: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:147 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Make sure Ubuntu is not set to turn off the monitor.

Comment: Do you mean under the power settings? These are my current values (https://imgur.com/a/P6V0JXL)

Comment: Do nto have links to pics give the info.

Comment: We're you able to solve this issue? I'm experiencing this right now. I also have HDMI to VGA converter

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04. Additionally, it causes my laptop to shut down.